# C# Closures in LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, closures

I am trying to create a dynamic query from expressions along the lines of:

```
string pName = "Shaun";
List<Person> people = Person.Select(p => p.Name == pName );
```

The problem comes in when evaluating the above expression.  I cannot retrieve the value of `pName` because it is a closure.  I have tried:

```
(ex as ConstantExpression).Value;
```

and

```
object result = new object();
(ex as ConstantExpression).Value.GetType().GetFields()[0].GetValue(result);
```

but I get a `"'Field 'pName' defined on type 'ConsoleApp1.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'System.Object'.'" exception`.

Also,

```
object res = (ex as ConstantExpression).Value.GetType().GetFields()[0].GetRawConstantValue();
```

has resulted in a `'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.' exception.`

How can I read the value from the closure object?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't compile. Person is a not an enumerable. Select requires a projection not a predicate. But maybe you wan't something like: Func<string, IEnumerable<Person>> people = (pName) => Persons.Where(p => p.Name == pName);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will receive better responses to your questions if the code compiles. Consider pasting your example in to http://www.dotnetfiddle.net to verify that it compiles. This guide too can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you trying to get people whose name is equal to the value of `pName`? Because if so, you need `.Where()`, not `.Select()`.

Comment: "Select" is not a Linq expression in this case.  I defined static methods "Select", "Insert" etc for database interactions.  But thanks for everyone's advice!

Answer (score 2):

If your question is simply "given the Expression<Func<T,bool>> (p => p.Name == pName ), How do I get the value of pName", here's the answer :

```
static string GetExprValue<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr){

    var body = expr.Body as BinaryExpression;

    var right =  body.Right as ConstantExpression;

    return right.Value.ToString();
}
```

Of course, this assumes a very specific format to the expression and code should be added to check that it's in the right format really...

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately, it only returns the name of the closure class.  But thanks for the advice!

Comment: Erm no, it returns a ToString() of whatever the right hand constant value of your expression is - If you see a class name there, it's probably a default ToString() implementation. See here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/XIxjA3

Comment: My apologeis.  I was thinking about the code inspector where the returned value would always be the class name.  Thank you for the clarification.  I tried to add the constant value as its original object into a SqlParameter array, therefore preserving the type.

Comment: In your code sample : 
string pName = "Shaun";
List<Person> people = Person.Select(p => p.Name == pName );

pName is a string. Your question makes no reference to SqlParameters ... perhaps you need to be asking a different question? ....

Answer (score -3):

I couldn't find a concrete answer to the above question on the Internet.  Through trial and error, I found that the original class has to be passed to the GetValue method as in:

```
object val = ((ConstantExpression)ex).Value;
object objectValue = val.GetType().GetFields()[0].GetValue(val);
```

Comment: This approach is a hack, it is not going to work with closures capturing multiple values, e.g. `p => p.Name == pName && p.Age == pAge` because you don't know if `pName` or `pAge` is going to be in `GetFields()` at index `[0]`.

Comment: Iterating through the array of fields should be sufficient to get the other properties, correct?  In my situation, only getting the first property is all I need